# How do I create a local kubernates cluster in a VM?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I have a set of docker images running in a Kubernates cluster on GKE. I have a Jenkins server running on a VM in GKE.

I have docker builds and GKE deploys running on the Jenkins server, but I would like to start up a 'local' cluster on the Jenkins server after successful builds, run my dockers in that cluster, run my tests towards the cluster, and then close down the local cluster before deploying the docker images to GKE.

I know about [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/), but they state that you are not able to run nested VM's, and I wonder if this blocks my dream of test my cluster before deploying it?

Do I have to run my local cluster on a physical server to be able to run my tests, or is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes ? Uses vagrant, maybe you can launch a vm within a vm.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need VM in VM? I'm not seeing why this is relevant.

Comment: try [conjure up](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/11/21/conjure-up-canonical-kubernetes-under-lxd-today). I haven't tried it but looks interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/)?

You can run a Kubernetes cluster within your Jenkins VM. Setup is a bit different than minikube and it's still in beta but it will let you test your cluster before the final deployment.